# Why is Process Builder not creating Pending Scheduled Action in production

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

I have a process builder that should create a scheduled action to occur in 2 days. It works ok in a sandbox but in production there is nothing listed under 'Paused and Waiting Interviews' even though the immediate action that preceded the Scheduled Action seemed to execute successfully as I can see the data update it made.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you should use [edit] to include a picture of the Process Builder decision node + action nodes for us to be able to help. And you can confirm that the PB is active in PROD?

Comment: Screenshot added. The PB is active on production. Just to add a bit more information on production it actually seem to add the entries in 'Paused and Waiting Interviews' but they vanished about an hour later. I tested on a sandbox on a 1 hour wait and it seemed to work ok. Re-testing again with a 2 day wait.

Comment: @scottrm a manual or other automated updates may have occurred on those records in production, causing them not to be valid anymore for the scheduled actions, hence removed from 'Paused and Waiting Interviews'

Comment: I chekced and the status of the records is sill not equal to 'Activated' so they should still be in the scheduled action

Comment: Just to update I have identiifed it is an update to the relevant records that is causing the Paused Interviews  to disappear but the status of the records is still at 'Activated' so I don't see why these updates should be having any impact. The updates also don't affect the fields that triggered the flow. Maybe because the IsChanged condition is not valid any more but that seems strange it would have cancelled the scheduled action.